# reaching value express session but hashing doesn`t give right value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, express-session

**What I want to do ?
I want to login and than show user`s weekly-reports. in order that user id need to givin if the user reports show. And I want to get this from session.**

`req.sessions.id` cant reach value of id across two function

in app.post("/auth", action....
 ~ file: app.js ~ line 66 ~ req.session.id Wh9cIUGQzJ1PNdv0i9qb2eiUIQ3-Iy_V
in findByWorkerId function
 ~ file: report.controller.js ~ line 28 ~ req.session.id.id C0yOICXX8dSFT3XLJZvf3D8NKtyEndH_

as you can see
`Wh9cIUGQzJ1PNdv0i9qb2eiUIQ3-Iy_V` 
and
`C0yOICXX8dSFT3XLJZvf3D8NKtyEndH_` values is not same.
I`m getting from the id colums from db and it is coming like id. for example 1, 3, 5

How can I check this session value ?

**app.post("/auth"**

```js
app.post("/auth", validatePayloadMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  req.session.test2 = "hello world";
  req.session.page_views = 1;


  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  if (username && password) {
    let sql =
      "SELECT username, password, id FROM workers where username = ? AND password=?";
    con.query(sql, [username, password], function (error, row, fields) {
      if (row.length > 0) {
        req.session.id = row.id;
        console.log(" ~ file: app.js ~ line 66 ~ req.session.id", req.session.id)
        req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
        req.session.username = row.username;
      } else {
        req.session.isLoggedIn = false;
        res.send("Incorrect Username and/or Password!");
      }
      res.end();
    });
  } else {
    res.send("Please enter Username and Password!");
    res.end();
  }
});
```

**findByWorkerId**

```
    exports.findByWorkerId = function (req, res) {
  const id = req.session.id;
  console.log(
    " ~ file: report.controller.js ~ line 28 ~ req.session.id",
    req.session.id
  );

  if (!id) {
    // 400 = bad request
    return res.status(400).send("The required path variable id is missing");
  }
  if (req.session.isLoggedIn) {
    Report.findByWorkerId(id, function (err, report) {
      if (err)
        return res
          .status(500)
          .send("Error occured during fetching report for id " + id);
      console.log("report: ", report);

      return res.send(report);
    });
  } else return null;
};
```

**app js config**

```
    var mysql = require("mysql");
var express = require("express");
var session = require("express-session");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require("cors");
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
var con = require("./config/db");

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "Shh, its a secret!",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
// to support URL-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

THANK YOU !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you used findByWorkerId at the following place .

```
if (req.session.isLoggedIn) {
    Report.findByWorkerId(id, function (err, report) {
      if (err)
        return res
          .status(500)
          .send("Error occured during fetching report for id " + id);
      console.log("report: ", report);
```

Comment: actually when user call /api/getall , the working func is `findByWorkerId`  and checking session.loggedIn